# How to ADD numbers in vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, addition

If I change the symbols at  {{ num1+num2+num3 }} with symbols for multiplication (*) or substraction (-) it works well.  However, when trying to add by using the (+) it simply concatenates.

```
    <div id="vue_mult">
    <input type="number" v-model="num1"  min="78" max="98" /> + 
    <input type="number" v-model="num2"  min="78" max="98" /> + 
    <input type="number" v-model="num3"  min="78" max="98" /> =
    {{ num1+num2+num3 }}
</div>
    <script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el:'#vue_mult',
        data: {  
            num1:0,
            num2:0,
            num3:0
        } //end data property 
    }) //end Vue object
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because the value of each input are automatically strings (hell, everything is a string in HTML/HTTP), therefore being concatenated by default. I would do the summation on a method (or a computed property) and convert the values to integers during the operation. This also separates some concerns -- making your template arguably cleaner.

```js
    const app = new Vue({
        el:'#vue_mult',
        data: {  
            num1:80,
            num2:80,
            num3:80
        },
        methods: {
            sum: function(nums){
                let result = 0;
                nums.forEach(function(n){ result += n * 1; });
                return result
            }
        }
//end data property 
    }) //end Vue object
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

    <div id="vue_mult">
    <input type="number" v-model="num1"  min="78" max="98" /> + 
    <input type="number" v-model="num2"  min="78" max="98" /> + 
    <input type="number" v-model="num3"  min="78" max="98" /> =
    {{ sum([num1, num2, num3]) }}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `reduce` is probably more appropriate and more terse than `forEach` if you're trying to combine all values of an array into a single value. `sum: nums => nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`, and you can remove the 0 if there's always going to be at least one element in `nums`

Comment: @CertainPerformance `.reduce()` is one of them Array methods that I haven't the time to explore yet so this is good info.

Answer (score 4):

**You simply need to parse the string into number and than you're good to go.**

Basically when you try to use `+` operator on string it does the `concatenation` not the addition.So to do mathematical operation you need to parse the string into numbers. something like this:-

```
 {{ Number(num1) + Number(num2) + Number(num3) }}
```

**Why it does work with the other symbols.**

When you call other any other operator except addition it internally changes  it number using `toNumber` function. so they work same as any normal number will.

```js
let sub = `1`-`1`;
let mul = `1` * `2`;
let div = `1` / `1`;

console.log(sub);
console.log(mul)
console.log(div)
```

Answer (score 3):

`num1`, `num2` and `num3` are strings, convert them to numeric first before adding:

```
{{ Number(num1) + Number(num2) + Number(num3) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`.number`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number) modifier for `v-model` directive which you can use in this kind of situations.

Here is an example:

https://codepen.io/bengu/pen/GRNXNbe

Comment: Will you show an example of how this is used?